# How to connect mysql database using PHP oop way?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am currently learning PHP and trying to figure out how to connect my MySQL database named (lead_gen_business) using OOP. I was given a task to get the specific output by the way. My problem is I am having a hard time connecting to my database. For the context of the code. I created a database and the code inside is a pre-built function that I modified for OOP.

Database

```
class Database
{
    public $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {

        if (!defined('DB_HOST')) {
            define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        }

        if (!defined('DB_USER')) {
            define('DB_USER', 'root');
        }

        if (!defined('DB_PASS')) {
            define('DB_PASS', 'Yourpass');
        }
    }

    public function connect($db_name)
    {
        $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $db_name);
    }

    /*-----------------------END OF CONNECTION PROCESS------------------------*/
    /*----------------------DATABASE QUERYING FUNCTIONS-----------------------*/
    //SELECT - used when expecting single OR multiple results
    //returns an array that contains one or more associative arrays
    function fetch_all($query)
    {
        $data = array();
        global $connection;
        $result = $connection->query($query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    //SELECT - used when expecting a single result
    //returns an associative array
    function fetch_record($query)
    {
        global $connection;
        $result = $connection->query($query);
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    //used to run INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE, queries that don't return a value
    //returns a value, the id of the most recently inserted record in your database
    function run_mysql_query($query)
    {
        global $connection;
        $result = $connection->query($query);
        return $connection->insert_id;
    }
    //returns an escaped string. EG, the string "That's crazy!" will be returned as "That\'s crazy!"
    //also helps secure your database against SQL injection
    function escape_this_string($string)
    {
        global $connection;
        return $connection->real_escape_string($string);
    }
}
```

```
    require_once('database.php');
    
    class Sites extends Database
    {
    
        public $client;
        public $havingArr = [];
        public $count = "COUNT(*)";
        public $id;
    
        public function select($myClient)
        {
            // Assuming $myClient is an array containing column names
            foreach ($myClient as $data) {
                $this->client = $data;
            }
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function group_by($siteId)
        {
            $this->id = $siteId;
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function having($paraCount, $greaterThan, $number)
        {
            // Building having condition
            $this->havingArr[] = "$paraCount $greaterThan $number";
            return $this;
        }
    
    
        public function get()
        {
            // $havingCondition = implode(" AND ", $this->havingArr);
            // $query = "SELECT {$this->client}, {$this->count} FROM sites
            //  GROUP BY {$this->id} HAVING $havingCondition";
            $query = "SELECT * FROM sites";
            // Assuming $this->connection->fetch_all is a method that executes the query and fetches all rows
            $result = $this->fetch_all($query);
    
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

And lastly...

```
    include('database.php');
    include('sites.php');
    
    
    class Query_builder extends Sites
    {
    
        public function __construct($db_name)
        {
    
            $this->connect($db_name);
        }
    
        public function show_get()
        {
            $datas = $this->get();
    
            foreach ($datas as $data) {
                echo $data['site_id'] . "<br>";
                echo $data['domain_name'] . "<br>";
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    }
    
    $show = new Query_builder('lead_gen_business');
    
    var_dump($show->show_get());
```

I got a lot of errors before this and the last error I got is this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\wamp64\www\OOP Fundamentals\Advance OOP\Query Builder\database.php on line 38

Sorry if it's too long. I already spent a day trying to figure out this independently. Any answer is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `global $connection;` you placed the connection into a class property called `$this->connection` Thats not Global its a class property

Comment: `also helps secure your database against SQL injection`....no, that's what prepared statements and parameters are for. escaping strings was how people thought they should do it 20 years ago, but since then better methods were created. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for details

Comment: What is the purpose of this `Database` wrapper class anyway? All it seems to do is just ape the existing mysqli functions, which are [available themselves with an object-oriented interface anyway](https://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/using-object-oriented-php-with-the-mysqli-extension/). It's not clear where it's really adding any value to have this extra code surrounding that. Even `fetch_all` doesn't add any value compared with recent mysqli versions, which already feature such a function

Comment: You are definitely over engineering this code. MYSQLI has itself a perfectly good class for accessing  a database

Comment: It may be useful to know which is `database.php on line 38` as we have no idea if you showed us everything in that file and currently line 38 is `return $data;` which does not match your error

Comment: Hi @ADyson. I am currently doing an assignment. The task is we should connect into our MySQL db using OOP and we should create 4 classes (the other 1 I didn't created yet because I cant still enter into my database) hence why you saw a bunch of class. We are just given a hint of what we should do and the rest is we have to figure out it on our own.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didnt still able to debug the errors in the Sites class because I still can be able to entry my database :(

Comment: `public function select($myClient)` Does nothing! Other than process over an array placing each occurance in turn onto a SCALAR property. All that achieves is to ignore all but the last value in the array. For Why I have no idea

Comment: `$connection->real_escape_string($string);` **V.Bad** Practice. See [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: **Exactly** which line is **line 38** of `database.php`

Comment: Also see the **First** Comment in this list and amend code appropriately

Comment: `The task is we should connect into our MySQL db using OOP`...technically all you need for that is the mysqli or PDO existing OOP interface. e.g. see https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#interface . Did they say what they thought these 4 classes should be doing?

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Atlas](http://atlasphp.io), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),  or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

Comment: Please do not put parentheses in random places. They make `include('database.php');` look like a function call, but it's not a function. Remove the parentheses and make it only `include 'database.php';`

Comment: If you are learning OOP then you must learn that inheritance should be avoided! Especially the way you use it. Inheritance should only be used to create subtypes. `Query_builder` is not a subtype of `Sites` nor `Database`. You should use composition instead.

Answer (score 2):

We've all done this mistake (me too!).

A database class is the worst thing to build in order to learn OOP. You aren't familiar yet with databases or classes, so you end up with creating a wrapper for the builtin database extension that does not add a single benefit, prevents you from using features that you still don't know that exist (prepared statements, getting auto-incremented IDs, handling transactions...) and often breaks basic functionality (such as error reporting).

Additionally, making your domain classes (`Invoice`, `Customer`, `BlogPost`...) extend your custom `Database` class is not only not useful, it also makes it very hard to design and understand application logic. Why? Because it doesn't make sense as inheritance relationship, so you end up being confused and unsure about how to proceed when you add more models.

My tips:

1. Use raw native database classes (`PDO` and `PDOStatement`, or `mysqli` and `mysqli_stmt` if you really don't find mysqli utterly counter-intuitive).
2. Don't make database connections and queries part of your application model design. Instead, consider them services (such as email delivery or PDF generation). The clases than handle such services belong to a separate hierarchy.
3. Global variables don't make coding easier, they make it *significantly* harder. It's not "cool, I don't have to pass variables along so my app will be easier to write", it is "drat, I don't know where my variables come from or are being changed, this is a mess".
4. Don't get obsessed with saving keystrokes, that should never be the purpose of application logic. You'll spend way more time thinking and debugging than typing, and if you really think your typing slows you down, you're efforts will be better invested in touch typing classes.

Answer (score 1):

You use `global $connection` in one of your functions, but when you created the connection, you assigned it to `$this->connection`, a class variable.

I think the important fact you're missing is that **these are different variables.**

You assigned the connection to `$this->connection`, but this does not assign the connection to the global variable `$connection`. A class variable is not a global.

Then when you try to use `global $connection` in one of your functions, that variable has nothing assigned to it. In PHP, you can reference variables that has not been initialized, but it is initially just `null`.

That's why you got the error when you try to call `$connection->query()`:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null

A variable with value `null` is not an object, and has no member functions. It's like trying to call a member function on a value of `true` or the integer `42`.

```
$my_var = 42;
$my_var->query(); // this would cause the same error
```

If you assign the connection to `$this->connection`, then you must use the same reference in subsequent functions of the class.

For example:

```
function fetch_all($query)
{
    $data = array();

    $result = $this->connection->query($query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Here the function uses `$this->connection`, assuming it was set by a prior call to the `connect()` function of the class.

There are also opportunities to improve your class in other ways, so the answer of what is the OOP way could be longer. But I'm answering only the reason for the error you showed in your post above.